# Community logout page redirects to Salesforce.com homepage instead of custom URL

Tags: community, logout

I have setup a custom logout URL for my Community via Communities > Worksspace > Administration > Login & Registration > Logout.

When I press the logout URL (which is `/secur/logout.jsp`) it directs to the Salesforce.com homepage instead.

Can anyone advise if its the wrong URL I am using? I can see that the session also is not destroyed when that logout.jsp is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is the full community URL needs to be specified before `/secur/logout.jsp`.

Adding `?retUrl=https://google.com/` will define where the site should redirect to after session has been closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `/secur/logout.jsp?retUrl=https://google.com/`. Here `google.com` is just an example. You can redirect to the URL you want. Ideally I would expect to do the way you've done but the above will also work.

Regards,
Ansuman